# Retrofit: GSON custom deserialization of children list

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I am having problems deserializing a custom object using gson.
I have this class:

```
public class Content implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private int tipo;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private Integer reward;
    /** Not-null value. */
    private String imageUrl;
    private String bannerUrl;
    private String logoUrl;
    /** Not-null value. */
    private String actionUrl;
    private Integer templateType;
    private String expiresAt;
    private Integer unlockReward;
    private Integer reportType;
    private String completionType;
    private Integer interactionType;
    private Integer productId;
    private Integer views;
    private Boolean saved;
    private Double weight;

    /** Used to resolve relations */
    private transient DaoSession daoSession;

    /** Used for active entity operations. */
    private transient ContentDao myDao;

    private List<Rule> ruleList;
    private List<Category> categoryList;
    ...
    // all getters and setters code
    ...
}
```

What I want is to deserialize the categoryList using a custom adapter. I created one using the following code:

```
Type typeOfListOfCategory = new com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<List<Category>>(){}.getType();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(typeOfListOfCategory, new JsonDeserializer<List<Category>>() {
    @Override
    public List<Category> deserialize(JsonElement element, Type type,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    // my code goes in here
    }
});
Gson gson = builder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();
```

And then I used it on a rest adapter

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("http://localhost/api")
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson)).build();
```

But my custom adapter is never called.

The json that I am receiving is like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "tipo": 1,
        "title": "title",
        "content": "content",
        "reward": 2.0,
        "image_url": "url1",
        "banner_url": "url2",
        "logo_url": "url3",
        "action_url": "url4",
        "template_type": 0,
        "expires_at": "2014-08-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "unlock_reward": 2,
        "report_type": 0,
        "completion_type": 0,
        "rules": [
            {
                "range": "1",
                "operator": "==",
                "key": "key1"
            }
        ],
        "categories": [
            {
                "description": "description"
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using `annotation` to tag the `Name` of the `JSON` field, your field name should match the `JSON`   field name. Like list of `List<Rule> ruleList` in your java class should be `List<Rule> rules` since the list name in JSON is `rules`. Cross check all the field names.

This is just my guess because you just said you have problem in deserializing which is very very vague term. If this solution does not work, post your error message  by updating your question.

Comment: Thanks. You were right about the ruleList and categoryList. The other fields (like actionUrl) are OK given the FieldNamingPolicy :). I will accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: More than half of your fields are wrongly named. for JSON converter the naming convention changes in Java. field should be all lowercase with underscore as separater .

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, only the list fields were named wrong. The rest are OK given the naming policy (which converts fields to Java standard automatically).

Comment: Alright. Was not aware of it . will update accordingly.